# error using a message redirection method (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

some months ago, I have implemented a GUI which contains a method that basically transfers the console output messages to a text area contained inside the GUI. The method works okay in some computers (in other words, it transfers and prints the messages from the console output and to the JTextArea outputText), but it fails to execute on others (nothing is printed). Here is some piece of code:

```
private JTextArea outputText;

private void redirectSystemStreams() {
    OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            write(b, 0, b.length);
        }
    };

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
}

private void updateTextArea(final String text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            outputText.append(text);
        }
    });
}
```

I believe the problem lies on the differences of the java versions installed on each computer, but I have no idea on how to solve this through code...

**UPDATE (27.08.14):** added additional explanation about the method behaviour...

**UPDATE 2 (27.08.14):** After analysing my project a little, I figured out that the problem exists because of a bad thread execution (it worked differently on some computers because one was not loading the dll which this thread uses...). The thread code is something like this:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private static final int sleepDelay         = 100;

    public MyThread() {}


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //do something...
            while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(MyThread.sleepDelay);
                //do something...
            }


        } catch(Exception e) {
                //do something...
            }

    }

}
```

It is important to know that both processes (`redirectSystemStreams()` and the thread above) do not access or share the same objects.
I have already done some researching about threads, but I am still really confused about what to do to solve this, basically because, at least for me, the `redirectSystemStreams()` is not a thread like the one in `MyThread`.

Comment: `... it fails to execute on others` if you _really_ want us to help you, you should help us first and explain in what way it fails. Exceptions? Not getting expected output (if you, what do you expect and what do you get)?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. When I say that it works, it means that it can transfer and print the output messages in the JTextArea. When it does not work, it means that nothing is printed in the JTextArea...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you sure `redirectSystemStreams()` is called on all systems? Do you get any hint on what could be wrong - exceptions, log messages etc.? Do the JVM versions differ or is it the same on every system?

Comment: the redirectSystemStreams() is only executed once, inside the GUI construction method. After this, all the messages should be printed inside the JTextArea. Also, there are no exceptions being thrown.

Java version on the PC the code works: 1.7.0_65
Java version on the PC it does not work: 1.7.0_60
Note: in my case, updating the java version should not be an option for now...

Comment: "one was not loading the dll which this thread uses..."
That doesnt make any sense. Are you mixing up languages here, perhaps?

Comment: "`while(true)`" -- thats about one of the worst beginners' mistakes. Once in a while, your app will deadlock and you wont know why. This is the root cause; NEVER use `while(true)` or something similar --- NEVER! There is no valid demand which cant be handled by a proper loop-condition.

Comment: Something like it. The project is really big and it uses lots of external devices. If there is no such device connected to the PC, some methods related to dlls may fail, even though the dll is loaded properly.
On the first PC, the redirection was possible because there were no devices, and because of that the thread did not interrupted the redirection method (because it failed, since it uses native methods). On the other hand, there were devices on the other PC, and it failed because the thread somehow blocked the redirection with its own execution.

Comment: Please, tell me if it is more understandable now...

Comment: not really, no ... but at least you now know why your thread deadlocks.

Comment: you mean it because of the while(true)?